Nestjs: injecting HttpService in unit test
I have a simple service
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}
  method() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
  }
}

And unit test:
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { SimpleService } from './test.service';

describe('test SimpleService', () => {
  let simpleService: SimpleService;
  let httpService: HttpService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HttpService,
          useValue: {
            get: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        SimpleService,
      ],
    }).compile();

    simpleService = module.get<SimpleService>(SimpleService);
    httpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(httpService).toBeDefined();
    expect(simpleService).toBeDefined();
  });
});

I expect HttpService will be injected into SimpleService via Test.createTestingModule, but it's not. I got error:
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SimpleService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
What am I missing?

Deep diving into problem i've found that HttpService is undefined when i import it in unit test
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
console.log('HttpService: ', HttpService) // HttpService: undefined

So the problem was module resolution in test env.
And fix is proper jest config for axios:
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^axios": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs"
    },
    ...


Original alias was "axios": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs" that also match to @nestjs/axios
